# react router changes base path on refresh

Tags: react-router

I am using react router v4. I noticed the same problem in v2 as well:

If I am at some route 
`/admin/details` 
and I do a page refresh, the root path of my app is changed to /admin. So any static assets loaded in index.html are missing because /admin is appended to the root path.

Same thing goes for api requests. If i want to make a relative API request from a nested route component, it breaks because rather than calling for example a `get('data/images') it would do`get('admin/data/images').

Any way around this? I've googled all day and nobody seems to run into this problem, the only answer is absolute paths for the requests.

Comment: have you got any code ?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out. I was calling my endpoint with a relative path ie I did
`get('data/all')` instead of `get('/data/all')` ...same thing with my scripts in the html. I just made them absolute and its all working. Sillyness.